# Infinite redirects with docker-compose, nginx and Blazor server app for SSL in Azure App Service

Tags: .net, docker, nginx, docker-compose, blazor

I've been trying to solve a problem over the last week but I don't seem to be getting anywhere so would really appreciate a steer in the right direction.

I've set up an Azure App Service, setting the configuration to run using docker-compose.

By and large, it's working - until I try to use SSL.

Here's my docker-compose.yml:

```
services:

  azuretest-web:
    image: xxx/xxx:azuretest-1
    expose:
      - "8000"
    environment:
      ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: Production
      ASPNETCORE_URLS: "http://+:8000"
    networks:
      - app-network
    depends_on:
      - azuretest-proxy

  azuretest-proxy:
    image: xxx/xxx:azuretestproxy-1
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - wellknown:/var/www/html/web/well_known
      - letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt
    networks:
      - app-network
    restart: always
      
volumes:
  nginx:
    driver: azure_file
    driver_opts:
      share_name: nginx
      storage_account_name: 1234
  letsencrypt:
    driver: azure_file
    driver_opts:
      share_name: letsencrypt
      storage_account_name: 1234
  wellknown:
    driver: azure_file
    driver_opts:
      share_name: wellknown
      storage_account_name: 1234

networks:
  app-network:
```

I build the docker image for nginx so that I can copy over my custom nginx.conf - which is as follows:

```
http{


    upstream web-app {
        server azuretest-web:8000;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name mydomainname.co.uk;
    
        

       location / {
           if ($scheme != "https") {
                return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
            }       
       }
    }
    
    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name mydomainname.co.uk;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomainname.co.uk/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomainname.co.uk/privkey.pem;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://web-app;
    
            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        }
    }


}
```

Under this configuration - it just goes into infinite redirects.  If you go in on http://mydomainname.co.uk then it redirects with a 301 as you'd expect to https.  After that, it redirects from https to https until the browser detects it and stops the request.

My guess is that the proxy pass to http://web-app is causing the problem - but then it's a pass-through, right?  So I'd not expect nginx to get involved in the request after pushing it over?

The Blazor app is barebones as a test (I've had to do this as my actual app is alot more complex - but it was muddying the waters over whether it was that or my config), so it's not set to run over HTTPS and is not performing a redirect from the app itself.

The only thing I've added to the app is the following (to try and solve this - it didn't work):

```
{
    ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
});
```

Anyone any ideas or experienced anything similar?  I've found a couple of posts relating to infinite redirects - but nothing suggested works.  For example, one mentioned removing the if condition on the rewrite rule.

So at the moment the only thing I can determine is:

- Maybe it's the proxy_pass to http - although I've seen numerous examples using the same?
- Maybe it's my certificate?  The certificate is valid - I am stretching a little.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

*Update*

Rather than add the Azure App Service to the mix, I've tried to recreate the problem locally via Docker desktop.

It's working fine locally.  So the redirect is working fine - from http to https - and the dotnet app is loading as I'd expect.

So the next obvious step is to replicate the docker-compose instructions (after pushing the images for nginx and the dotnet app to docker-hub).  I did that - and you'd think that it'd be like-for-like and work the same.

Nope - no joy.  Same problem.  I'm completely flummoxed. The only thing I can think of is that Azure is somehow getting in the way.